# How to change font size of only one BarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I found this code in another thread, but I want to change only one button font size.

```
if let font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext", size: 15) {
oneBarButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], forState: UIControlState.Normal)}
```

So where do I have to put the code and is this correct?

Comment: You tell us. Where _did_ you put the code and what happened when you did?

Comment: i put it in my main ViewController and created an outlet to this button. I tried viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear but it didn't work, so basically nothing happened

Comment: Don't describe your code. _Show_ it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put this code in `viewDidLoad` method of your `ViewController`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20);
    barButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], forState:UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Your code may not work because you have not font named `AvenirNext`.

**Update**

Working code for Swift 4 / iOS 11:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    barButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue: font], forState: .normal)
}
```

Comment: is there a way to center that button then because its going more to the top

Comment: Try this `barButtonItem.setTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, 20), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default);`

Comment: that button is not moving i used it for displaying text because i found no way of using a label in a toolbar

Comment: Actually you _can_ use label on toolbar programmatically. Take a look into doc https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithCustomView:

Answer (score -1):

For Objective C,

```
 [barbutton setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                                     NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13.0],
                                     NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]
                                     } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```